# Long-running async salt job seems to timeout

Tags: saltstack

I have a long-running async job that doesn't produce output for a long time at one point of the job ...  It is terminating early - during the part where there is no output for a while - but the master is seeing it as having completed successfully.

It seems like the minion is timing out but still reporting back to the master that it finished successfully ...

Anyone run into this?  Know how I can resolve?  Thanks!!

Comment: How are you running it? How are you checking its status? How do you know it actually failed?